# Error is coming after I run the Eclipse.exe and giving the workspace

Tags: eclipse

When I run the Eclipse.exe within the given folder, it is starting. And after I give the workspace and click ok, an error is coming as "An error has occurred. See the log file F:\ABstudies\eclipse\yyyy..". please help me.

[image]

The log file is as follow,

[log file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JfSRf.png)
[log file- other part](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TCwgQ.png)

Comment: Do what it said. What's in the log file?

Comment: We need to see what is in the .log file.

Comment: @greg-449 I updated it with the log file..

Comment: @nitind i updated with log file..

Comment: You are trying to run Eclipse 4.6.3 (Neon) with Java 15. Neon is 13 releases old and will not run with Java 15. Either use the current Eclipse 2021-03 or use Java 8.